# How to access information schema using a pypika query?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pypika

I'm trying to get the names of the columns from a table in an Azure SQL database using a PyPika SQL query, but keep running into trouble. Here's the code I'm using to generate the query:

```
def dbView(table):
    infoSchema = ppk.Table("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS")
    return ppk.MSSQLQuery.from_(infoSchema).select(infoSchema.COLUMN_NAME).where(infoSchema.TABLE_NAME == table)
```

I created another function that uses the PyODBC library to get the SQL from the query, execute it against the database, and return all the rows:

```
def getData(query: ppk.Query):
    '''
    Execute a query against the Azure db and return 
    every row in the results list.
    '''

    print("QUERY: ", query.get_sql())
    conn = getConnection()
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query.get_sql())
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

I know the getData() function works because when I pass it a simple select query, everything works correctly. However, when I try to use the query generated by pypika above, I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

To make sure this wasn't just some kind of permissions error, I wrote the following query by hand and executed it using the getData() function and it worked just fine:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Validation'
```

I also printed out the query that pypika generated to the console. The only difference appears to be the addition of some double quotes:

```
SELECT "COLUMN_NAME" FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" WHERE "TABLE_NAME"='Validation'
```

What am I doing wrong? For some reason, this error appears to be limited to specifically the information schema table, because I have used similar queries several other times in my code without issue. I know I can just use the query I wrote by hand, but the point of using PyPika was to make all my SQL queries more readable and reusable - it'd be nice to understand why it doesn't work in this very specific situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you (or why is this PyPika thing, whatever that is) surrounding “INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS” (or anything, really) in double quotes? Have you talked to their support team? Not sure how many of your peers here are going to know what that is, never mind how to fix it.

Comment: Also, use `sys.columns` unless your primary goal is to write a query that might also work in a few of the other database platforms too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand As far as why it adds double quotes around the table and column names, I have no idea. I learned SQL using an Oracle server so assumed double quotes were the standard day to reference things using Microsoft's syntax, but apparently not?  I'll open a ticket on GitHub if this turns out to not be my fault. In reference to using sys.columns, will do - thanks! Out of curiosity, what's the difference between using information schema and using sys?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is _fine_ for the absolute basics (or if you need portability), but it's incomplete, doesn't get updated for new features, and the documentation has actually warned against trusting it in several places. I blogged about it here: [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views). That's not going to solve your problem, of course; your application seems to have been written to either pretend that schemas don't exist, or at least ignore by default that you would never use anything but `dbo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It apparently has an API to schema-qualify tables.

> from pypika import Table, Query, Schema
>
> views = Schema('views')
>
> q = Query.from_(views.customers).select(customers.id, customers.phone)

https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_tutorial.html#tables-columns-schemas-and-databases

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really understand the difference when I read the documentation so it went right over my head. 

`infoSchema = ppk.Schema('INFORMATION_SCHEMA')` `(ppk.Query.from_(infoSchema.COLUMNS).select(infoSchema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME).where(infoSchema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME == table)`